# How To create a Role Based Access System On A Web Application Using Tokens in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So Basically what I want to achieve here is to allow logged in users to access pages that their role/access level allows them to while preventing those with a lesser or different roles from accessing the higher access pages (EX. obviously I don't want students to be messing around with the library's database and thus this privilege/access to the webpage with that function is reserved for teachers and above) Additionally I also don't want users that aren't logged in from accessing anything other than the sign up and login page.

So far I have some basic infrastructure here on the backend which writes the users access level on their token upon logging in:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // Import jsonwebtoken for token generation

const connection = require('../database/connector');
const config = require('../Misc/Config');

router.use(bodyParser.json());

// Define the login route
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    // Check if the username and password are provided
    if (!username || !password) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'Username and password are required.' });
        return;
    }

    // Query the database to find the user by username
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM accounts.loginfo WHERE username = ?';
    connection.query(sql, [username], async (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred during login.' });
        } else {
            // Check if the user exists
            if (results.length === 0) {
                res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid username or password.' });
            } else {
                // Verify the password
                const user = results[0];
                const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

                if (!passwordMatch) {
                    res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid username or password.' });
                } else {
                    // User is authenticated; create a JWT token and send it back to the client
                    const token = generateAuthToken(user);

                    // Include the user's access level in the response
                    res.status(200).json({ token, access: user.access });
                }
            }
        }
    });
});


// Function to generate a JWT token
function generateAuthToken(user) {
    // Generate a JWT token with user data and a secret key
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id, username: user.username }, config.secretKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });
    return token;
}

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the corresponding log in front end:

```
// Wait for the DOM to load
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
} else {
    ready();
}

function ready() {
    const loginpassword = document.getElementById('loginpassword');
    const togglePasswordButton = document.getElementById('ShowPass');

    togglePasswordButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (loginpassword.type === 'password') {
            loginpassword.type = 'text';
        } else {
            loginpassword.type = 'password';
            togglePasswordButton.textContent = 'Show Password';
        }
    });

    // Add event listener to the Login button
    const loginButton = document.getElementById('Login');

    loginButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const username = document.getElementById('loginuser').value;
        const password = document.getElementById('loginpassword').value;

        // Validate user input
        if (!username || !password) {
            alert('Please enter your username and password.');
            return;
        }

        // Create an object with login data
        const loginData = {
            username,
            password,
        };

        // Send a POST request to the backend login route
        fetch('/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(loginData),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                if (data.error) {
                    // Display an error alert if login fails
                    alert('Login failed. Please check your username and password.');
                } else {
                    // Store the token securely in localStorage
                    localStorage.setItem('authToken', data.token);
                    
                    // Determine where to redirect based on user's access
                    if (data.access === 'teacher') {
                        window.location.href = '../Teacher-Pages/T-Home.html'; // Teacher dashboard URL
                    } else if (data.access === 'student') {
                        window.location.href = '../Student-Pages/S-Home.html'; // Student dashboard URL
                    } else {
                        alert('Invalid user access.'); // Handle other access types as needed
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error); // Log the error for debugging
                alert('An error occurred during the login process.');
            });
    });
}
```

Both of these JS does work and i have tested and logged if a token i create when a user logs in, and it does. but i am at a loss how to proceed with the Role Based Access System, i am fairly new to full stack web dev so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Import the signup and login routes
const signupRoute = require('./routes/signup');
const loginRoute = require('./routes/login'); // Import your login route
const logoutRoute = require('./routes/logout')

// Serve static files from the 'public' directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Middleware to parse incoming JSON data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Use the signup and login routes with their respective prefixes
app.use('/api', signupRoute);
app.use('/api', loginRoute); // Add the login route
app.use('/api', logoutRoute);

// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3002;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: When I see this I advise you to use server-side rendering with express, for which you can use the ejs rendering model (https://ejs.co/).
So if the user's role is teacher, you can render the teacher page.